# Integration for $\int_a^b f(k-x)dx$

Tags: integration

Knowing that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=F(b)-F(a)$. What if $\int_a^b f(k-x)dx$ assuming k is a constant which is always greater than x, a, and b?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}k - x = -1$$

Therefore
$$\int_a^bf(k - x)\mathrm dx = -\int_a^b-f(k - x)\mathrm dx = -\left[F(k - x)\right]_a^b = F(k - a) - F(k - b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Make the substitution $u=k-x$ and change the limits accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take    t = k-x
   =>.   dt = -dx. , since  k Is constant

Now look at the limits how they changes 
First upper limit ,x=b => k-t =b here I replaces " x" by k-t  ( see at first take)
=> k- t =b 
=> t =k-b is our upper limit now

Now for lower limit  x = a 
                   => k-t    =a 
                    => t = k-a is our lower limit now

Now from the given result that F( b ) - F(a)

Just replace the results as follows

- {F( k-b)  - F(k-a)}  here you have a "-" sign at first ,why  because we have 
  dt =- dx 
  This is answer .... Enjoy ...hope u like it